# How to display the values in a list from the database in flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a problem I want to show values from my database to list but this does not work I have tried several methods and nothing still does not work.

**Route**

```py
@app.route('/t',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Consulta():
    g.con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=AUS_COMPUTO02\SQLEXPRESS; DATABASE=WEBSERVICE; Trusted_Connection = yes;')

    cur= g.con.execute("SELECT *FROM PROVEEDOR WHERE DECRIPCION  = '{}'".format('CHEF'))
    posts = [dict(ID_PROVEEDOR=row[0], DECRIPCION=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()] 
    g.con.close()
    print(posts)
    return render_template('consulta.html', posts=posts)
```

**HTML**

```html
    <from name="des" action="{url_for('t')}" method='POST'>

        <select  name="des" >
       <option value="{{ID_PROVEEDOR}}">{{ DECRIPCION }} </option>
       <option value="2"></option>

        </select>

        <input type="submit">

         {% for p in post %}

        <strong>ID_PROVEEDOR:</strong> {{ p.ID_PROVEEDOR }}
        <strong>DECRIPCION:</strong> {{ p.DECRIPCION }} 
             {% endfor %} 
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named the variable with posts as `posts` when calling `render_template` but refer to it as `post` in the template:

```
{% for p in post %}
```

instead of

```
{% for p in posts %}
```

Note, that variables pass to render_template with the names of respective keyword arguments:

```
render_template('consulta.html', posts=posts, foo="bar")  # posts and foo can be used in the template
```

So, you need to pass `DECRIPCION` and `ID_PROVEEDOR` as well

Comment: Thanks very much for helping me